# What do these Maven Liquibase errors mean?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml, liquibase

When I try running "mvn compile" in the command prompt, I get these errors.

> WARNING: Liquibase skipped due to Maven configuration
>
> WARNING: Using platform encoding  to copy filtered
>   resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

Comment: googling the "Liquibase skipped due to Maven configuration" leads to the liquibase page http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/update-mojo.html at least.

Comment: I solved the issue. Had to add some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Liquibase you're using. If it's 3.3.3, then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894421/liquibase-3-3-3-refusing-to-run-due-to-maven-configuration) and [this issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2360) on the Liquibase site (helpfully found for me by [@Tome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169091/tome)).