# Liquibase 3.3.3 refusing to run "due to maven configuration"

Tags: maven, liquibase

Did something change in liquibase between version 2 and version 3?

I have the following in my pom file...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-changesets.xml</changeLogFile>
                <driver>${db.liquibase.driver}</driver>
                <username>${db.liquibase.username}</username>
                <password>${db.liquibase.password}</password>
                <url>${db.liquibase.url}</url>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>${db.liquibase.promptOnNonLocal}</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And I get the following when I run **liquibase:update**...

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building ********** 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.3:update (default-cli) @ ********** ---
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Liquibase skipped due to maven configuration
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```

This runs perfectly well if I revert to using version 2.0.5 of the liquibase plugin.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Didn't you configure the plugin to be skipped `<skip>true</skip>` in some parent POM?

Comment: @Tome - nope. There is no parent pom for this project and I haven't set skip to be true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check here: [CORE-2360](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2360)
It looks like `<skip>` is set to true by default in *3.3.3* version. Just use *3.3.4* and it should be OK.

Comment: So I *haven't* done anything wrong which is re-assuring :)